# How to move gmail attachment to cloud storage?

Tags: google-workspace

I am suppose to move attachment from Gmail directly to cloud storage, Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to move attachment(s) from a single Gmail email to Google Drive (or perhaps another cloud storage)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can contact to Gsuite support [1].

[1]https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en#